# Recursively filter & sort files by timestamp

Tags: linux, unix, ls

I wanted to recursively search a directory for a particular file extension, and wanted the files to appear by timestamp (i.e. newest ones first).

Ideally, I'd want something like:

```
ls -R -lth *.txt
```

but this doesn't work, although parts of it work:

```
ls -lth *.txt
ls -R -lth
```

How do I need to modify my 'ls' command?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `bash`, you could enable the `globstar` shell option and use `**/` to match zero or more subdirectories:

```
shopt -s globstar # enable globstar
ls -lth **/*.txt
shopt -u globstar # disable globstar
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this, because it also works with a large number of files

```
find . -name '*.txt' -printf '%T@ %t %p\n' | sort -k 1 -n
```